# Will Lego Universe be available for digital distribution?

Tags: lego-universe

Will be there some kind of digital distribution for Lego Universe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official support site [says](https://en-us.support.universe.lego.com/):

> LEGO Universe will be available both on DVD and for download at LEGOuniverse.com. More specifics about how to get the game will become available closer to the launch date.

Comment: Not true. No digital download there, even if you buy the game online at LEGO website.

Comment: LEGO Universe is not currently available for download at the LEGO site, but is available on Steam for Windows.